# Get pixel distance in meters for mapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to know how much meters is a certain pixel distance, at a given zoom level.

Reason: I want to know the radius, in meters, of a circle in the mapView, which fits perfectly in the mapView -> `radiusPixels = mapView.getWidth()/2;`

I found the method `mapView.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(radiusMeters)`, which does the opposite of that what I need. But there's no inverse for this method or anything else useful.

My (probably naive) approach to solve it is as follows:

```
private double getFittingRadiusInMeters() {
    return getMeters(mapView.getWidth() / 2);
}

private double getMeters(int pixels) {
    Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
    Point mapCenterPixels = new Point(mapView.getWidth() / 2, mapView.getHeight() / 2);

    //create 2 geopoints which are at pixels distance
    GeoPoint centerGeoPoint = proj.fromPixels(mapCenterPixels.x, mapCenterPixels.y);
    GeoPoint otherGeoPoint = proj.fromPixels(mapCenterPixels.x + pixels, mapCenterPixels.y);

    Location loc = new Location("");
    loc.setLatitude(centerGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);
    loc.setLongitude(centerGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);

    Location loc2 = new Location("");
    loc2.setLatitude(otherGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);
    loc2.setLongitude(otherGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);

    return loc.distanceTo(loc2);
}
```

But it doesn't work well. I always get circles which are far smaller than the mapView - the radius is too small.

I know the distanceTo method says "approximate" but the radius differ significantly from the expected size. Should not be an effect of the approximation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your approach.

You are calculating the value for screen half with at screen center level. The distance found is only valid to draw a circle at the same Latitude value (the Longitude may change without problem).

Because earth is shperic, the distance for the same number of pixels calculated at different Latitude levels, produces different results. Moving from Equador level to position closer to Pole level, same number of pixels result a in smaller distance in meters.

However, this will only be noticable if you call `getFittingRadiusInMeters()` with map positioned in a very distant Latitude from where you draw the circle.

Otherwise, it should work fine.

**Solution**

The method `getMeters()` should receive as parameter a `GeoPoint` (or at least the Latitude) that should be used to calculate the distance.

Regards.